# Codeigniter control db data should be in model or controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on codeigniter. I want to ask that where should i check(Is it false? Come 0 record or more? vs.) data comes from db? In model or in controller? Now I check its in controller.

Comment: check num rows `in controller` fine.. Model is useful for database operation. place calculation code in Model  and return result into controller

Comment: $query = $this->db->get('table_name'); if($query->num_rows() >0){return true;}else{return false;} :)

Comment: for database manipulation use your model :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on you logic and code style. I prefer do it in model with the data modification if need (mysql date to data/time), and return the result array. In this way you can write a clearer controller with less nested If methods, also in views echo foreach :)

Answer (score 0):

The goal of the Model is to interact with the database: `select`, `insert`, `update`, `delete` [...] data. By the way, Model is not always a database. But it is, most of the time.

Following your needs, The first idea would be to do the check in the controller.

If you do not use the result got from your model for another treatment inside the controller. Do the check in the view. For instance, in the case you want to know if you have retrieve products from your database I prefer to do it in the view :

```
if( count($possibleData) > 0) {
  foreach($possibleData as $values) {
    // Show your data
  }
} 
else {
  echo 'no products';
}
```

To conclude, I would not do the check in the Model. To me, **both Controller and View are correct**, but not inside the Model which the aim is just to get / push data.

Comment: sorry for pushing in but, I'm new to Codeigniter too, and You said that the "goal of the Model is to interact with the database: select, insert, update, delete [...] data. By the way, Model is not always a database". What else is the MODEL used for? (if not just the DB)

Comment: I just wanted to point it because some people say that model is used only for the relation with the database. It's true and false because your data can be, for instance, stored in a file. I've never never had this case but it can happen. It's how works the MVC, not just pointed for CodeIgniter. (and btw say it before someone tell I'm wrong with  _"What is a Model"_ ;))